# How to disable the password strength meter script on reset password page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to disable the password strength meter script on the reset password page.

[image: Password strength meter]

The solution I tried below doesn't work perhaps because the handle is wrong or I'm hooking to the wrong action.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
}, 100 );
```

How can I disable the password strength meter script on the reset password page?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to hide the password strength meter, you could do so via CSS.

In your plugin

```
function login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login', plugins_url( 'login.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_stylesheet' );
```

In login.css (hide box and change border-color of inputs)

```
body.login-action-rp #pass-strength-result {
    display: none;
}
body.login-action-rp #pass1,
body.login-action-rp #pass1-text {
    border-color: rgb(221,221,221) !important;
}
```

---

If you want to completely remove the script, you need to dequeue `password-strength-meter` as well as remove the dependancy that `user-profile` has on that.

```
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  wp_dequeue_script('password-strength-meter');
  wp_dequeue_script('user-profile');
  wp_deregister_script('user-profile');

  $suffix = SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
  wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile', "/wp-admin/js/user-profile$suffix.js", array( 'jquery', 'wp-util' ), false, 1 );
});
```

To be honest I didn't check for full functionality, in my local example it all worked fine without the script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my aim is to stop the script from loading.

Comment: @henrywright Please see my update

Comment: Haven't checked but does user-profile.js run without errors if one of it's dependencies is removed?

Comment: @henrywright If you add info why you're doing this, I might be able to help you better. For now this exceeds the time I am able to put into this post. The posted script does successfully remove the password strength script from loading, as well as I showed you how you can simply hide it with pure CSS